# How to use OR logic in istio virtual service header exact match?

Tags: service, header, httprequest, istio

I have two services running and 4 different headers. I want to direct requests with headers `a` and `c` to one service and `b` and `d` to another service. What is the best way to achieve that in a virtual service manifests?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sample_virtualservice
  namespace: sample_namespace
spec:
  hosts:
    - sample_service.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        x-test:
          exact: "a" OR "c" //This doesn't work but I want to achieve.
    route:
      - destination:
          host: service_1.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 80
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: service_2.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

I believe there must be a better way instead of mentioning the same route destination multiple times in a manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a clean solution of using `regex` instead of `exact` which allows us to send requests to the same destination for different headers without mentioning the same route destination multiple times in a manifest file.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sample_virtualservice
  namespace: sample_namespace
spec:
  hosts:
    - sample_service.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        x-test:
          regex: "a|c"
    route:
      - destination:
          host: service_1.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 80
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: service_2.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

Comment: if this meets your requirements, which it seems to, can you please mark it as the Accepted answer? (it's ok to do that even though it's your own answer)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are not logical operators in istio virtual service.

They are only available in [rules](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/istio.policy.v1beta1/#Rule) and [mixer expression language](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/expression-language/).

---

As you mentioned for now the only option is to use the same route multiple times.

So virtual service would look like this.

```
http:
- name: "a"
  match:
  - headers:
      x-test:
        exact: "a" 
  route:
  - destination:
    host: service_1.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
      port:
        number: 80
- name: "b"
  match:
  - headers:
      x-test:
        exact: "b" 
  route:
  - destination:
    host: service_1.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
      port:
        number: 80  
- name: "c"
  match:
  - headers:
      x-test:
        exact: "c" 
  route:
  - destination:
    host: service_2.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
      port:
        number: 80
- name: "d"
  match:
  - headers:
      x-test:
        exact: "d" 
  route:
  - destination:
    host: service_2.sample_namespace.svc.cluster.local
      port:
        number: 80
```

---

Additional info, I see you have virtual service deployed in sample_namespace, remember that [gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) should be deployed in the same namespace. If it´s not, you should add it like in below example.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: some-config-namespace
```

Check the `spec.gateways` section

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-Mongo
  namespace: sample_namespace
spec:
  gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway
```